# Set max content width if size greater than 800 px

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I would like to set max content width to 800px where screen width more than 800 px.

How I can do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add these constraints,

1. Center the view horizontally in the superView. Let's say its priority is X.
2. Equal width to superView. Its priority should be is X-1.
3. Add another constraint - Width less than equal to 800 with priority X.